# Starting a MP4 download from a php script

Tags: php, file, download, header

So I have this small PHP condition for a PHP download, it's been working fine for weeks then all of a sudden I noticed it's stopped working.

Rather than getting a download of the file, the users are getting a 0kb file instead.

I have checked the URL and it's still working as expected.

Here is the code

```
if ($refer == 'stackoverflow.com' || $refer == 'dev.stackoverflow.com') {

        $fichero = $downloadUrl;

        if ($fichero) {
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fichero));
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fichero));
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($fichero);
                exit;
        } else {
                die("The File $fichero does not exist");
        }
} else {
        die("Sorry you must start the download from the website");
}
```

Now I know it's hitting the conditionals, because I am not getting any of the die statements and the file is still being offered as a download. This seems to have broken in Chrome and also IE(Edge). I have been doing some reading regarding headers and the only documentation on this proble I can find that appears to be relevant is the expires setting which i set to 0.

Am I missing an easy trick here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does `var_dump(filesize($fichero));` output?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I didn't think to dump the var. So I stuck this in the if $fichero) - boolean false . So that is my problem

Comment: Interesting, I can see filesize(): stat failed for URL in the apache error logs, but the URL posted when placed in a browser works immediately.

Comment: I believe it may be a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fichero));
```

Was causing the issue, I should have debugged this a little more before posting.

This file needed write in order to suppress this warning

PHP Warning:  filesize(): stat failed for

When removing

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fichero));
```

The code worked as expected, I tweaked with chmod on the file and re-enabled the above code and it fixed my issue.

Thanks